# How to stop Azure worker without losing any message?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-worker-roles

Actually, when I want to stop my worker on azure, this function is called.

```
    public override void OnStop()
    {
        if (messageProvider != null)
        {
            messageProvider.StopListening();
        }

        base.OnStop();
    }
```

When I upgrade the worker, If there is any message beeing processed, I lose that message. Do you know how can I safely stop my worker?

Comment: Who implemented that "message provider" thing?

Comment: Can you provide more information - are you reading messages from a queue/servicebus? What (generally/high level) is involved in processing a message?

Answer (score 0):

You have five minutes, from the time `OnStop()` is called, and before `OnStop()` exits, to finish your current processing (whatever that means). In your case, it looks like you have some type of message provider, and you're able to disengage from message-consumption via `messageProvider.StopListening();`. Since you're concerned with processing of current message, you'd likely need some type of signal to let you know that there are no messages being processed (including ones that may have been read, but not processed, by the time you called `StopListening()`), and that it's safe to exit from `OnStop()`. How you implement the signal is up to you, but you'd need to wait for the signal within `Onstop()`.

FYI info about `OnStop()` and the five-minute window is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleentrypoint.onstop.aspx).