# how to gracefully stop worker role with service bus queue

Tags: azure, servicebus

Hi we have a requirement we are using service bus to read message and process some data based on that message and we are using workerrole for better performance.

The issue is when we try to deploy the workerrole any service bus message listener which is processing the request which is in action gets terminated by onStop() method and my data get's corrupted. and I have to again push a message for the ongoing request.

What I want is a mechanism to gracefully stopping the worker role so that it process the existing message request before exiting and stop listening to new message. How do I do that.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe your issue in more detail, please? E.g. by adding code, commands or screen shots which describe your problem. Please have also a look to the Help Center, especially for [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Comment: This is (or *was* - web & worker roles are not really used much anymore) a common scenario, and I answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32561257/how-to-stop-azure-worker-without-losing-any-message/32564858#32564858) about 3 years ago.